# Is it possible for Nul $A$ to span $\Bbb R^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know Col $A$ can span $\Bbb R^n$, but what about Nul $A$?

Comment: If $A=0$ its null space is all of $\mathbb{R}^m$ where $A:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n.$

Comment: Yes, take $A$ to be the zero matrix

Comment: Of course the null space is a subspace of the domain, so it won't span the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unless $A$ is the zero matrix itself.